# Question about linear independence and span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence

Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three sets.
$A\subset \Bbb{R}^2$ and $\textbf{0} \notin A$.

I need to prove that if $ B,C$ are any two sets such that $B \cap C = \emptyset$  and $\emptyset
\neq B,C \subset A$,
$\operatorname{Sp}(B) \cap \operatorname{Sp}(C)=\{\textbf{0}\}$

so $A$ is linearly independent, any helps?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is not a "do it for me" site. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to hlo.

Comment: I don't have an idea at all. an hint will be okay too.

Comment: Try writing down some examples of sets $A,B,C$ that satisfy the hypotheses. How large can a linearly independent set in the plane be?

Answer (score 2):

Let $0\notin A\subset \Bbb{R}^2$

Since $  \emptyset\neq B, C\subset A$ there exists $0\neq u\in B, 0\neq v\in C$ and $B\cap C\neq \emptyset$ implies $u\neq v$

Then $u\in \operatorname{sp}({B}) , v\in\operatorname{sp}({C})$

Since $\operatorname{sp}({B}) \cap \operatorname{sp}({C})=\{0\}$ , $\{u,v\}$ Linearly independent.

$\{u, v\}\subset A$ .

Claim :$\{u, v\}=A$

Suppose $\exists w\in A$ such that $ w\notin \{u,v\}$ . Clearly $w\neq 0$ .

Now the set $\{u,v,w\}$ is linearly dependent in $\Bbb{R}^2$ . Then one vector is combination of other two.

Suppose $w\in \operatorname{sp}(\{u, v\}) $

Then for $B=\{u, v\}$ and $C=\{w\}$ we have $B\cap C=\emptyset$ but $w\in \operatorname{sp}(B) \cap \operatorname{sp}(C) \neq \{0\}$

Contradiction.

Hence $A=\{u, v\}$ which is linearly independent in $\Bbb{R}^2$.