# Proof verification: Prove that the union of 3 subspaces of V is a subspace iff one of the subspaces contains the other two

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I know that this question has been asked a number of times and I get the other proofs, however I'd like to see if my proof is valid as well. I also know that this statement is only true when F is not a field with 2 elements.

My proof: (Doesn't prove the claim directly, but brings the problem down to a simpler one which I have already proved)

Let $U_1,U_2,U_3$ be subspaces of V and $A = U_1 ∪ U_2 ∪ U_3 $

Assume that none of the subspaces are contained in each other.

Choose some vector $v_1 ∈ U_1$ that is not in $U_2$ or $U_3$. Choose another vector $v_2 ∈ U_2$

If the union of $U_1,U_2,U_3$ is a subspace, that means it is closed under addition and thus $v_1+v_2 ∈ A$

This means, $v_1+v_2$ is either in $U_1,U_2$, or $U_3$.

$v_1+v_2$ cannot be in $U_2$ or $U_3$ because if that was the case, $v_1 ∈ U_2$ or $U_3$ which goes against the fact that it is in neither.

This means that $v_1+v_2 ∈ U_1$ which then means that $v_2 ∈ U_1$

This then shows that for any vector in $U_2$, it also belongs to $U_1$ which shows that $U_2$ is contained by $U_1$

This then reduces the proof down to showing that the union of 2 subspaces is a subspace iff one is contained in the other which I have proved already.

My question/what I need help with: Does my proof for bringing this down to a problem of 2 subspaces work?

Here is the proof that I took some inspiration from with a similar assumption:
[image]

Comment: Why should the assumption provide $v_1\in U_1$ such that $v_1\notin U_2$ and $v_1\notin U_3$?

Comment: Since I assume none of the vector spaces are contained in one another? I'm not particularly sure my "proof/logic" is correct so any advice/tips would be appreciated

Comment: You can find $v_1\in U_1\setminus U_2$ and $v_1'\in U_1\setminus U_3$. There's no reason why you can find a single vector satisfying both conditions.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thank you for your feedback. I was initially under the doubt that I couldn't do that but I saw a similar proof on quizlet which I will attach that made the initial assumption I did so I continued with it. Do you have any ideas as to what I can change as so the rest of the proof still works or does my idea simply not work?

Comment: @igameonamac see here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489433/977780